# How to change docker port?

Tags: macos, docker

I have installed docker desktop on my macOS, now it's running in port 8000, how can I change to another port? because I want to use the 8000 port in another application. thanks

Comment: How did you start the container?  In general you need to delete and recreate the container with the new published port.  The Docker Desktop app on its own shouldn't open a network listener.

Comment: I haven't run any containers, just run docker desktop, and when I check port 8000 with command `lsof -i tcp:8000` the result is like in the picture https://ibb.co/8Dh3B6b

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop for MAC itself does not run on a port.
It's a container running on a port.

The container has an internal port (within the container) and you can map that to a port on the host.
Mapping is done with "ports" on docker-compose.

For example, the file below has port 3011 internally on the Container, and this is mapped to 80 on the host

```sh
version: "3.9"

services:

  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "Web"
    env_file:
      - env.settings
    ports:
      - "8080:3011"
```

(This script is missing a Dockerfile obviously. Let me know if you want a full working example)

Suppose this is running a simple NodeJS/Express Webserver.

If you are in the container, then access that Webserver on port 3011.
But on your host the Webserver is accessed on port 8080.

Comment: I haven't run any containers, just run docker desktop, and when I check port 8000 with command `lsof -i tcp:8000` the result is like in the picture https://ibb.co/8Dh3B6b

Comment: I see your screenshot, and it is strange.  When I run Docker Desktop on my Mac, I do not get port 8000 occupied by Docker. Can you do a "docker ps -a" command in a terminal and make sure you have no containers running?